# Does not implement interface member (C#)

Tags: c#

> 'StringToVisibilityConverter' does not implement interface member
>   'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert(object, System.Type,
>   object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)'

Any idea what's wrong with this? As far as I know my imports are correct

```
public class StringToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is string)
        {
            var input = (string)value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty("Name"))
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: Did you read that error message correctly?  You are missing ConvertBack().

Comment: Yeah just realised, it's only early mornings here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you also need to have this method when you inherit IValueConverter:

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the ConvertBack method as well. [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
 //Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx I see that must implement and ConvertBack.

The issue could appear event the class CultureInfo is not from System.Globalization.CultureInfo and is a custom class.